# Scala val unrecognized in playframework

Tags: scala, playframework

please, i trying to use a val parameter in a for template but it is unrecognized

```
@{val slide=0 }
            @for((parent, index) <- grandparents.zipWithIndex){
                @for((son, jndex )<- parent.zipWithIndex){
                    @{slide++}
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't declare and use a Scala val in the templates.
You need to declare a *reusable value* using the `defining` helper, as explained in the [template engine](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTemplates) section of the documentation.

(plus, you can't change the value of a... `val`; you must use the `var` keyword)

Answer (score 0):

As an extension to Samy's answer, here's what your `@defining` block might look like:

```
@defining(grandparents.foldLeft(0)((i,parent) => i + parent.size) {slide =>
  // Insert any markup here that depends on the value of slide
}
```

Comment: thanks, is a something like @defining(0) {slide => where slide is a var and not a val, i would like use for in brakes